# On click not working?

Tags: javascript

On each page of the website, the menu has different classes for each page that moves the menu image up and down to show which is selected.

Just to give the impression of a fast loading when the page transitions with effects, I need to use JS to instantly position the background image, instead of having to wait for the next page.

This doesn't seem to work, and I put the alert code to see if it is even loading the 
function, but it doesn't

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Fs92Y/1/

**HTML:**

```
<li><a href="index.html" onclick="javascript:menuchange('1');">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="what-we-do.html" onclick="javascript:menuchange('2');">What we do</a></li>
<li><a href="our-clients.html" onclick="javascript:menuchange('3');">Our clients</a></li>
<li><a href="testimonials.html" onclick="javascript:menuchange('4');">Testimonials</a></li>
```

**JS:**

```
function menuchange($itemclicked){
    document.getElementById("Menu").className = "page" & $itemclicked;
    alert("Code has been launched!");
}
```

Comment: Remove `javascript:` to start with.

Comment: I added it as another stackoverflow answer mentioned it. didn't make a difference

Comment: Replace `&` by `+`. `&` is bitwise-or, you're looking for string concatenation.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens `&` is a bitwise AND, not OR: `|` is OR.

Comment: Well, you simply navigate another page. So your code wont have any effect actually.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Woops, that's a typo. Thanks for correcting!

Comment: @Joey: Make sure the javascript is defined in the `<head>` section of your page. Remove the `javascript:`; it's not needed. You will need to prevent the browser's default behavior (navigating to the href). Also, make sure `#Menu` element exists.

Comment: Actually, I think you *do* want to browse to the different pages when you click the links, but what you haven't realized is that web pages are stateless. Running the JavaScript on click does not permanently change the class names. It has to be re-run *every time a page loads*.

Comment: @Cory I know this already. It works fine as each page has a different class. I would like to add page transitions when the links are clicked, but this means for the second or 2 that the page takes to transition, the background for the menu hasn't changed until the page changes. I want to give the impression that the page is loading instantly, so that the background changes as soon as it is clicked. It's not a big issue, just a thought.

Comment: Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fs92Y/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use `"page" + $itemclicked`, not `"page" & $itemclicked`.

```
document.getElementById("Menu").className = "page" + $itemclicked;
```

`&` is a [Bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) in JavaScript, which performs a bitwise AND on two numbers, returning a number. `"page" & 1` returns `0`.

Comment: I see thanks. Although still doesn't work. Someone said it was because you cant have href and onclick.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to have both, that's not the problem. It would help us pin things if you could explain what you mean by "doesn't work" - what's happening that shouldn't, and/or what's not happening that should?

Comment: For me his code is throwing menuchange is undefined

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer. It fixed some issues with my code, how ever it still doesn't work. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fs92Y/1/

Comment: @Joey Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Fs92Y/2. You had 3 errors: 1. You were still using `"page" & $itemclicked`; 2. Your JavaScript was being loaded before the HTML; 3. Your element has an `id` of "menu", not "Menu" (it's case-sensitive).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Thanks! Don't know how I missed that stupid lower case m! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error code in javascript, use + not & for concatenate string:

```
function menuchange($itemclicked){
     document.getElementById("Menu").className = "page" + $itemclicked;
    alert("Code has been launched!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All that you need to do is change your & to an + for example :

```
document.getElementById("Menu").className = "page" + $itemclicked;
```

Comment: The most likely reason is because your javascript is executing befire the page is ready. If you have jQuery linked add the following change :
`function menuchange($itemclicked){ 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById("Menu").className = "page" + $itemclicked;
        alert("Code has been launched!"); 
    });
}`

Comment: @DrRoach: If the question isn't tagged with jQuery, we can't assume that OP is or even wants to use it.